# $\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_{i}^{2}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}} \leq \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_{i}$

Tags: inequality

I was wondering if for $x_i\in\mathbb{R}_{\geq0}$ the inequality
$$
\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_{i}^{2}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}} \leq \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_{i}
$$
Holds. If so, is there a name for it?

**My attempt**

$$
\sum_i^n i = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}
$$
$$
\sum_i^n i^2 = \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}
$$
Since the right hand side is $O(n^{3/2})$ and the left hand side is $O(n^2)$, and n is a positive integer, the inequality should hold.

Comment: Why on earth should the equality hold in general *just because* it holds for one extremely special case (the case you mentioned)?

Comment: @user21820,  looks like a typo (that was edited).  The word *"inequality"* was cut (now pasted back together).

Comment: @mjw: I meant "inequality" in my comment, and my objection is correct when that typo is fixed.

Comment: You are writing about the "attempt" not the actual problem statement, right?  The inequality is true in the statement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know whether there's a name for it, but note that\begin{align}\left(\sum_{i=1}^nx_i\right)^2&=\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^{\,2}+\overbrace{\sum_{i\ne j}x_ix_j}^{\geqslant0}\\&\geqslant\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^{\,2}\end{align}and that therefore$$\sum_{i=1}^nx_i\geqslant\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^{\,2}}.$$

Answer (score 5):

Yes.  It is the triangle inequality (for right triangles).

To explain.  Consider a point $x=(x_1,x_2, \cdots, x_n) \in \mathbb{R}_{\ge 0}^n$.

$$|x|= \left(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2\right)^{1/2}$$ is the diagonal of a hyperparallelapiped. The sum of the "legs" is $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i$.

We can prove it by induction on $n$.

$$\sqrt{x_1^2 + x_2^2} \le x_1+x_2. \quad (*)$$  Also known as $(x_1+x_2)^2=x_1^2+x_2^2+2x_1x_2 \ge x_1^2+x_2^2$.

Assume $$\sqrt{x_1^2+ \cdots x_{n-1}^2} \le \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} x_i$$

Let $y=(x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_{n-1})\in \mathbb{R}_{\ge 0}^{n-1}$.

$$|y|= \left(\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} x_i^2\right)^{1/2}$$

Now apply $(*)$ to $\{|y|,x_n\}$.

Comment: Looks like somebody didn't understand this answer.  Sorry about that.

Comment: Was not me! +1.

Comment: @Blade, didn't mean you.  Anyway, will try to write more clearly going forward $\cdots.$

Comment: Neutralizing +1 for a geometric approach.